# How to fix Dropbox (Windows client) "Can't sync filename" error?

Tags: sync, dropbox

My Dropbox Windows client shows an error:

[image]

I suspect `Current` is a folder uploaded from my Dropbox Mac client, that somehow cannot be synced to Windows.

**How can I get the exact location of this file/folder ?**

**Are there any logs I can read to get more information on the cause of the sync error?**

Comment: you shouldn't have to "suspect" anything! You can open Dropbox in a browser and check for yourself. Also, if there's a problem with the folder, the webpage is the best place to check it

Comment: What should I check for myself? I see no such error message on my Dropbox web account.

Comment: You can check for any error messages or warnings. If you find nothing then you can check the problematic "Current" folder to maybe understand where it comes from and eventually find out if there is something wrong with it.